# AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items' in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am customizing in the DRF to give an error response value if a null value is entered in the body or title. However, after squeezing the code, the test results in the following error.

> AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'

I don't know what this error means, and I don't know why it happens. Can you tell me what the problem is in my code? Here's my code.

views.py

```
class CreatePostView (ModelViewSet) :
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
```

serializers.py

```
class PostSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    author = serializers.CharField(source='author.username', read_only=True)
    title = serializers.CharField(allow_null=True)
    text = serializers.CharField(allow_null=True)
    image = ImageSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['pk', 'author', 'title', 'text', 'like', 'liker', 'image', 'view']

    def validate (self, attrs) :
        title = attrs.get('title', '')
        text = attrs.get('text', '')

        error = {}

        if title is None and text is None :
            error['message'] = '제목과 본문을 넣어주세요.'
            raise serializers.ValidationError(error)

        if title is None  :
            error['message'] = '제목을 넣어주세요.'
            raise serializers.ValidationError(error)

        if text is None :
            error['message'] = '본문을 넣어주세요.'
            raise serializers.ValidationError(error)

        return attrs

    def create (self, validated_data) :
        return Post.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kurak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 102, in view
    for method, action in actions.items():
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import CreatePostView
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('post', CreatePostView.as_view({'post', 'create'})),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: add complete error traceback

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I add it

Comment: add your urls.py

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I add it too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be **`{'post':'create'}`** instead of `{'post', 'create'}`